# Is there any way to pass all variables in the current scope to Mako as a context?

Tags: python, templates, mako

I have a method like so:

```
def index(self):
    title = "test"
    return render("index.html", title=title)
```

Where `render` is a function that automatically renders the given template file with the rest of the variables passed in as it's context. In this case, I'm passing `title` in as a variable in the context. This is a little redundant for me. Is there any way I can automatically pick up all variables defined in the `index` method and pass them all as part of the context to Mako?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the technique given below:

```
def render(template, **vars):
    # In practice this would render a template
    print(vars)

def index():
    title = 'A title'
    subject = 'A subject'
    render("index.html", **locals())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    index()
```

When you run the above script, it prints

```
{'subject': 'A subject', 'title': 'A title'}
```

showing that the `vars` dictionary could be used as a template context, exactly as if you had made the call like this:

```
render("index.html", title='A title', subject='A subject')
```

If you use `locals()`, it will pass local variables defined in the body of the `index()` function as well as any parameters passed to `index()` - such as `self` for a method.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this snippet:

```
def foo():
  class bar:
    a = 'b'
    c = 'd'
    e = 'f'
    foo = ['bar', 'baz']

  return vars(locals()['bar'])

for var, val in foo().items():
  print var + '=' + str(val)
```

When you run it, it spits this out:

```
a=b
__module__=__main__
e=f
c=d
foo=['bar', 'baz']
__doc__=None
```

The `locals()['bar']` chunk references the class `bar` itself, and `vars()` returns `bar`s variables. I don't think you can do it with a function in realtime, but with a class it seems to work.